# how to write junit test for janusgraph

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server

Generally, we are using some clusters as db to ingest and fetch the data for janusgraph while writing with java .coming to junit testing I'm trying to mock the variables as required

```
@Mock
GraphTraversalSource g;

@Mock
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Map<String, Object>> traversal;

@Mock
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal1;
```

but while I'm returning it is giving nullpointer exception ,i even tried adding data eg:

```
g.addV("jobRole").property(single,"jobCode","xyz").property(single,"vLabel", "JobRole");
```

still the result is null

```
GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal =
   graphSource.V().has("vLabel", "JobRole").has("jobCode", JOBCODE);
Vertex JobRole = traversal.hasNext() 
    ? traversal.next() 
    : graphSource.addV("JobRole").property(
          VertexProperty.Cardinality.single, "jobCode", JOBCODE).next();

graphSource.V(JobRole).property(
    VertexProperty.Cardinality.single, "vLabel", "JobRole").next();
```

I need to mock this.

should I have to add all the data by creating a dummy memory or what can I do ,how can I mock the above given vertex with properties?

Comment: Do you want a unittest that tests the code that uses JanusGraph via the GraphTraversal API? Then you have to instruct your traversal mock instance how to behave, see e.g. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html to add return values to the mock object.

Comment: graphSource.V().has("vLabel", "JobRole").has("jobCode", JOBCODE); this is the query,how do i return a vertex to it without connecting to server even if i mock (vertex.class) it is throwing as nullpointer exception

Answer (score 1):

For mocking fluent API's the java Mockito class for creating mocks has a feature called "deep stubbing". An excellent explanation is available on https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-fluent-apis